# Team Services: Nuget Packager task failing

Tags: azure-devops

I have a Build definition in Team Services that includes a Nuget Packager task. I'm using Hosted build agents.
In the last couple of builds this task began to fail, with the following message:

```
2017-02-22T21:43:24.9318762Z C:\LR\MMS\Services\Mms\TaskAgentProvisioner\Tools\agents\2.112.0\externals\nuget\NuGet.exe pack "D:\a\1\s\src\app\Ormie\Ormie.csproj" -OutputDirectory "D:\a\1\s" -Properties Configuration=release
2017-02-22T21:43:25.5460318Z MSBuild auto-detection: using msbuild version '14.0' from 'C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\14.0\bin'.
2017-02-22T21:43:25.5460318Z Attempting to build package from 'Ormie.csproj'.
2017-02-22T21:43:25.7480272Z Packing files from 'D:\a\1\s\src\app\Ormie\bin\Release'.
2017-02-22T21:43:25.9040273Z Using 'Ormie.nuspec' for metadata.
2017-02-22T21:43:26.1645370Z ##[error]'System.Collections' already has a dependency defined for 'Microsoft.NETCore.Platforms'.
2017-02-22T21:43:26.1865365Z ##[error]System.Exception: Unexpected exit code 1 returned from tool NuGet.exe
2017-02-22T21:43:26.1865365Z    at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.DistributedTask.Task.Internal.InvokeToolCmdlet.ProcessRecord()
2017-02-22T21:43:26.1865365Z    at System.Management.Automation.CommandProcessor.ProcessRecord()
2017-02-22T21:43:26.2015355Z ##[error]PowerShell script completed with 1 errors.
2017-02-22T21:43:26.2025352Z ##[section]Finishing: NuGet Packager
```

In order to understand what was happening, I tried to create the package in my development box, using NuGet version 3.3, and got a similar message. So, I've updated NuGet to version 3.5, tried to pack in my machine and it worked just fine.
So, my questions are:

- Is there any kind of configuration in Team Services Build Definition
  that can be done to solve this issue?
- How can I force the Hosted    build agent to use version 3.5 in the
  NuGet Packager task?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To use nuget3.5 for nugget packager task, you can add nugget.exe to source control, and then use `$(Build.SourcesDirectory)\nuget.exe` as **path to nugget.exe**.

[image]

For **Nuget Restore** and **Nuget Publisher** Tasks, they define 3.3 and 3.5 in their tasks. You can view `task.json` for all tasks definitions in [VSTS task](https://github.com/Microsoft/vsts-tasks/tree/master/Tasks).

If you want **Nuget Packager** also can choose nugget version, you should develop your own task same as Nuget Packager function and with nuget version to choose.

Comment: I was hoping to avoid having nuget.exe in my source control. I guess NuGet 3.5 must be there somewhere, as it can be selected in the Nuget Installer task. Is this the only option? Is this really a bug/issue is VSTS?

Comment: Since you are using hosted agent, the softwares cannot controlled/installed. The softwares deplyed by hosted agent as https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/build/concepts/agents/hosted. If you don't want add nuget.exe in your source control, you can use your own deploy agent if it meets your other requriments.

Comment: I'm sorry, as stated since my question and in my comments, I just don't get it. Why do **Nuget Restore** and **Nuget Publisher** tasks allow me to choose nuget version (3.3 or 3.5) and **Nuget Packager** won't. Is it just me to find this really odd!?

Comment: For **Nuget Restore** and **Nuget Publisher** Tasks, they define 3.3 and 3.5 in their tasks. You can view `task.json` for all tasks definitions in https://github.com/Microsoft/vsts-tasks/tree/master/Tasks. If you want **Nuget Packager** also can choose nugget version, you should develop your own task same as **Nuget Packager** function and with nuget version to choose.

Comment: Thanks, that was userful.

Comment: We'll be updating the NuGet Packager task in an upcoming sprint to enable the same version picker that's currently available in the Installer and Publisher tasks. We'll also be making NuGet 4.0 available as part of that update.

Comment: If you'd like to avoid checking in nuget.exe (recommended, esp. for Git repos), I've documented a workaround here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/42637744/297050