# Choose Nuget Packager version in Visual Studio Team Services build step

Tags: .net, build, azure-devops

Why I cannot choose nuget version in build step configuration in Visual Studio Team Services? It seems that for every other nuget build step (installer, publisher) I can choose between 3.3.0 and 3.5.0, but for this one I'm forced to download nuget.exe, check it into source control and provide a path to the exe.

[image]

Since nuget 3.3.0 cannot deal with making packages directly from project.json it would make so much sense to be able to choose the version in this step.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I cannot think of any good reason and looking at the repository for the tasks they were created by separate developers, maybe a comms mix-up, who knows? :)

You can see by looking at the task.json for the Packager [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/vsts-tasks/blob/master/Tasks/NugetPackager/task.json) and the Publisher [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/vsts-tasks/blob/master/Tasks/NuGetPublisher/task.json) that it just wasn't implemented for the Packager - it's here on [L91](https://github.com/Microsoft/vsts-tasks/blob/master/Tasks/NuGetPublisher/task.json#L91) of the Publisher.

Issue [#3636](https://github.com/Microsoft/vsts-tasks/issues/3636) was logged for it, once fixed this will be available on VSTS shortly after.

Comment: It was an oversight that only the Installer and Publisher tasks were updated with the version picker. But, we'll be updating the NuGet Packager task in an upcoming sprint to enable the same version picker that's currently available in the Installer and Publisher tasks. We'll also be making NuGet 4.0 available as part of that update.

Comment: Well, here is a pretty good reason... https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/46036/nuget-packager-systemreactivecore-already-has-a-de.html

Comment: @Alex, was this fix ever made? I still do not see the ability to specify the NuGet version. We are using the latest build agents from GitHub and TFS Version 15.117.26714.0.

Comment: Yep! See here for full details. Best experience on TFS 2017 U3 and later, but there's a workaround for all versions as well. https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/devops/2017/09/29/using-the-latest-nuget-in-your-build/

Answer (score 4):

Yes, the nuget version is defined in **NuGet Publisher** task, but not in **NuGet Packager** task so far. If you need to choose nuget version, you can develop your own task similar with **NuGet Packager**. All VSTS tasks code are [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/vsts-tasks/tree/master/Tasks) for your reference.

**Option2:** you can add the nuget version you wan to use in source control, and add the path in **NuGet Packager** task. Details you can refer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42403436/team-services-nuget-packager-task-failing/42408821?noredirect=1#comment72012467_42408821).

Answer (score 4):

I had this exact same issue and received a very helpful response from a MS support technician. This downloads 3.5.0 to a temp location if it doesn't already exist, so avoids having to have nuget.exe in your source control system.

1) Add Task of type Powershell script and place it above your Nuget Packager step.
2) Set Type to "Inline Script"
3) Replace default Inline Script value with this:

```
$v = '3.5.0'
$u = "https://dist.nuget.org/win-x86-commandline/v$v/NuGet.exe"
$p = Join-Path ([IO.Path]::GetTempPath()) "NuGet-$v.exe"
Write-Host "##vso[task.setvariable variable=downloadedNuGetExe]$p"
if (Test-Path $p) { return }
Invoke-WebRequest $u -OutFile $p
```

4) In Nuget Packager build step, set Path to Nuget.exe value to the variable we just set:

```
$(downloadedNuGetExe)
```

Hope this helps, and thanks to the MS support technician, Aruna, for this solution!

Answer (score 3):

[Update 11/29/2017 with new feature information]

The NuGet Tool Installer task is the preferred way to manage the version of NuGet used in your build. See [this blog post](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/devops/2017/09/29/using-the-latest-nuget-in-your-build/) for more info.

Comment: Thanks for this Alex! Here's my question regarding your answer since I'm pretty new to this. How do I add a powershell script and what do you mean by the NuGet Packager step? Any comment or link to check out will be pretty much appreciated.